# Problem (with) doing something

Tags: prepositions, idioms

When you want to say that you had or are having problems with something, what is the best way to express this:

> I'm having a problem **with** saying this correctly.
>
> I'm having a problem saying this correctly.

Another example:

> There is a problem **with** sending this form.
>
> There is a problem sending this form.

Comment: I think there is no problem in saying "in saying" rather than "with saying" here, but, maybe, I'm wrong.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: I think Nicolás is asking whether he needs any preposition at all, not whether *with* could be replaced by *in*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either will be understood, and can be correct, but in my opinion the inclusion of the word "with" has a connotation of a more general problem.

> There is a problem sending this form.

This probably implies that there is a specific problem with the form, that prevents it from being sent.  Perhaps you forgot to include your last name, and the web site is rejecting it as invalid.

> There is a problem with sending this form.

This *could* suggest a more general problem, which is preventing sending the form, or which may result from sending the form.  It may not be a problem with the form directly, but perhaps your Internet connection is not working.  Or perhaps your computer has caught fire.  Or it may be that if you submit the form, a problem will arise--perhaps your employer will discover you are looking for work elsewhere.

*with* could also suggest a personal or moral objection, rather than a practical, problem:

> I have a problem with going to strip clubs.
>   She had a problem with the way he sang.

Comment: I agree, a *problem with* may be talking about a problem that could result from sending the form.  The *sending* may work just fine, but you might not want to send it because that will cause X to happen.

Comment: @Jim: Good addition; answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

I think Flimzy is on the right track, but hasn't quite got there.

Omiting the preposition entirely has the effect of linking the *problem* and the *action* more closely. Thus, in a sentence like...

> *There is a problem getting my book published*
>   we assume the action itself is being somehow hindered (maybe I haven't finished the last chapter).

...but...

> *There is a problem **with** getting my book published*
>   implies doing the action will *cause* a problem (maybe I'll have to start paying tax on the income).

Note that this is only a *tendency*. Most native speakers won't normally be aware of the distinction, nor will those who are aware make the distinction themselves with any consistency.